# CSS img max-width: 100%

Tags: html, css

If we specify max-width: 100% for an image element (for example an image of 250px * 500px) and we put this image inside a parent element of width 1000px, then if the parent is shrunk <= 500px, the image will be shrunk accordingly to occupy the full length of the parent. However, if the parent's width is at > 500px, the image won't be scaled up but at its original 500px.

What confuses me is the meaning of 100% here. From my understanding, the relative percentage is always with regards to its parent. So doesn't it mean that the maximum width is always the current width of its parent? So the image will always be shrunk/scaled up to fit its parents because the max width is 100%? What am I misunderstanding here? how to understand the relative percentage used in max-width in this case? **What is it relative to?** Thanks!

Comment: Per MDN, using a percentage value for `max-width` "_defines the `max-width` as a percentage of the containing block's width._" So your assertion that it is relative to the parent is correct.  I am not understanding the scenarios you describe in which you are seeing potential conflicts in the behavior-- would it be possible to include one or more [mcve]s and/or clear, ordered steps to reproduce the behavior, including the expected and actual behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference between `width` and `max-width`.

This definition from w3school will make it easy for you to understand.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

> The `max-width` property defines the maximum width of an element.
>
> If the content is larger than the maximum width, it will automatically
> change the height of the element.
>
> If the content is smaller than the maximum width, the max-width
> property has no effect.
>
> **Note:** This prevents the value of the `width` property from becoming
> larger than `max-width`. The value of the `max-width` property overrides
> the `width` property.

Coming to your question now, if you replace `max-width` with `width` and check for the width of your image for break point >=500px or <500px, it will of-course take parents full width.

But as is mentioned from the above definition, `max-width` makes sure the element width does not go above a certain width (no matter what is the parent width) and that's why this property was brought into.

Comment: you use should official sources instead, such as W3C or MDN. w3schools is inaccurate.

Comment: @Raptor: I admire your advise, I myself prefer official sources. However MDN or W3C is still not that bad for beginners. We all started from these sites and with time though we noticed w3c does has few issues in some cases but for a beginner to understand a point, I do not feel it is bad to share :)

Anyways, Thanks